# US Dollars abroad

Tags: india, money, exchange

On my next trip to India I was thinking of exchanging some US dollars I have left from travelling into rupees. I have now realised that they are 2006, 2009 and even one 1998 100 USD notes; do you foresee any problems with that?

Comment: These are 100% legal tender. Finding a changer who is willing to accept them is your only hurdle.

Comment: Old banknotes are much easier to exchange in the US than outside the US.

Comment: In India, you will have trouble exchanging notes larger than 20 US $. Make change before you fly.